# How to pass XAML (or another ContentView) to ContentView as children

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

I am trying to create one ContentView and inside that I want to pass children as XAML or (another Content View). How can I do that?

**E.g.:**
I have one view say Header.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:strings="clr-namespace:Eurynote.Localization.Resources.en;assembly=Eurynote.Localization"
             x:Class="Eurynote.Core.Views.Common.EurynoteHeader">
    
    <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Image Source="brand_icon" WidthRequest="32" HeightRequest="30" />
        <Label Text="Header" Margin="0,-3,0,0" />

        <!-- Render dynamic content pass as children here -->

    </HorizontalStackLayout>
    
</ContentView>
```

Now, in my MainPage.xaml file I can call this view as

```
<common:Header />
```

and it's working fine.

but How can I pass another control to the same content view as children like button, label, etc... or any other ContentView as shown in two below examples.

```
<common:Header>
    <Button Text="Button" /> 
</common:Header>

<common:Header>
    <common:AnotherView />
</common:Header>
```

I want to make sure only single content can be passed like [Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/frame?view=net-maui-8.0).

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I have got one solution:
Assuming I have a custom ContentView called `Header.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"         
             xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Core.Views.Common"
             x:Class="Core.Views.Common.Header">

    <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" ColumnDefinitions="*,*">

        <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Image Source="brand_icon" WidthRequest="32" HeightRequest="30" />
            <Label Text="Header" Style="{StaticResource DarkLabelHeader}" Margin="0,-3,0,0" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <!-- Dynamic content placeholder -->
        <ContentView x:Name="dynamicContentContainer" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End">
            <ContentView.Content>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="dynamicContentPresenter"/>
            </ContentView.Content>
        </ContentView>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

In the code-behind (Header.xaml.cs), update it to use the new .NET MAUI APIs:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty DynamicContentProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DynamicContent), typeof(View), typeof(Header), null);

public View DynamicContent
{
    get => (View)GetValue(DynamicContentProperty);
    set => SetValue(DynamicContentProperty, value);
}

public Header()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string? propertyName = null)
{
    base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

    if (propertyName == DynamicContentProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        dynamicContentPresenter.Content = DynamicContent;
    }
}
```

In your main XAML file (MainPage.xaml or similar), we can use HeaderView like this:

```
<common:Header>
    <common:Header.DynamicContent>
        <common:SampleView /> <!-- any view or children -->
    </common:Header.DynamicContent>
</common:Header>
```

**My personal opinion:**
This solution solved the requirement but has few redundant lines of code at two places:

- I need to specifically use this (`<common:Header.DynamicContent>`) wrapper outside children in `MainPage.xaml` file. Which I think shouldn't be required as it can have only one child like [Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/frame?view=net-maui-8.0)
- I'll have to specify `OnPropertyChanged` in xaml.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you use the following code, the contentview's content will be covered by the Button.

```
<common:Header>
    <Button Text="Button" /> 
</common:Header>
```

So you can't add child for the contentview from the xaml. But you can do this in the code behind. Such as:

In the xaml:

```
<common:Header x:Name = "header">
```

In the page's constructor:

```
public partial class MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var layout = head.Content as HorizontalStackLayout;
    layout.Children.Add(new Button(){ Text = "new button"});
}
```

You can add new item into the contentview as children by this way.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply @liyun-zhang-msft but this is not the ask of the question. I need to show ContentView data as well as Children data(which can be dynamic) from the parent component

Comment: Did you mean you want to pass the child in the contentview to other control? @AjayKumar

Comment: The code I used will set the new button as the 3rd child of the HorizontalStackLayout in the header contentview and the image and label will keep in it.  @AjayKumar

Comment: Or you may want the [ContentPresenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-8.0#substitute-content-into-a-contentpresenter) for the contentview's control template? @AjayKumar

Comment: Hi @LiyunZhang, Yes, I want to pass View to another view. Till now, I am successfully able to use Bindable property and ContentPresenter to pass view to another view as child but I have to pass like this: 
`<common:Header>
 <common:Header.DynamicContent>
  <common:SampleView />
 </common:Header.DynamicContent>
</common:Header>`

But I want to pass we direct child as default child because I want to restrict ContentView to accept only single child, 
So I want Something like below, Which I am not able to solve :
`<common:Header>
 <common:SampleView />
</common:Header>`

Comment: If so, you can just get the 3rd child in the HorizontalStackLayout such as: `var child = (head.Content as HorizontalStackLayout).Children[2];` and then pass it. @AjayKumar

Comment: You even don't have to use the `ContentPresenter`. And if you use it, the `var child=(head.Content as HorizontalStackLayout).Children[2]` will get a  `ContentPresenter`. Then you can pass the `(child as ContentPresenter).Content`. @AjayKumar

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have put my finding as answer below this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77787913/2639185.  If you have better approach, please mention that as well. Thank you again!!!

Comment: You are welcome. If you want to add child in the xaml, your solution is a good way. The bindableproperty is must for it. And my solution can only add child in the code behind. @AjayKumar